# Buttons in a nav go below with Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css

I have a display problem on the main navigation of my website, where I put two buttons at the end of the items.

On Chrome, Firefox and IE, everything works:
[image]

But with Microsoft Edge, the two buttons are below the rest:
[image]

Here is the code of my navigation :

```css
#mainMenu>ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: static;
}

.nav-pills>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainMenu" class="main-menu mega-menu">
  <ul class="main-menu nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">A propos</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/commentCaMarche">Comment ça marche ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/avantages">Les avantages mysite</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/#offres">Offres</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/designs">Mises en page</a></li>
    <a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/register/" rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-default btn_nav_large hidden-xs">Inscription</a>
    <li class="visible-xs"><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/register/">Inscription</a></li>
    <a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/login" rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-default btn_nav_large hidden-xs">Connexion</a>
    <li class="visible-xs"><a href="/mysite/web/app_dev.php/login">Connexion</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your CSS please

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` elements can be children of `<ul>` elements but you have `<a>` as well.